# How to change label number and text with method from another Class?

Tags: c#, class, methods, label

I have different Labels on my Form1 and want to change the text of a single Label using the same method.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 change = new Class1();
        change.ChangeLabelText();
    }

    public void ChangeLabel(string msg, Label label)
    {
        if (label.InvokeRequired)
            label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label.Text = msg; }));
        else
            label.Text = msg;
    }
}
```

how can i pass label1 or label2 as i need?

```
class Class1
{
    public void ChangeLabelText()
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.ChangeLabel("Surname", label2);           
    }
}
```

label2 is underlined of red: NOT EXIST IN THE ACTUAL CONTEST

Comment: Why you need to send Label to the function? just use the exists label in your form

Comment: Your `label2` is a part of `Form1` that is why it is not known to the `Class1` . What you could do, is make the labels public and then pass them something like this: `frm1.label2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to make Class1 raise an **Event** with the Name of the Label and the String to change it to.  Your Form will receive the event, find the Label itself, and update the value.  This way Class1 never needs a reference to Form1 or any of the Labels.  It's still a bad design as you need to know the name of the Label, but this is the direction you went down anyways.

Here's what Class1 would look like:

```
public class Class1
{

    public delegate void dlgChangeLabel(string lblName, string newValue);
    public event dlgChangeLabel ChangeLabel;

    public void ChangeLabelText()
    {
        if (ChangeLabel != null)
        {
            ChangeLabel("label2", "SurName");
        }
    }

}
```

Back in Form1, we need to subscribe to the ChangeLabel() event when we create our instance of Class1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 change = new Class1();
        change.ChangeLabel += Change_ChangeLabel;
        change.ChangeLabelText();
    }

    private void Change_ChangeLabel(string lblName, string newValue)
    {
        // see if we have a Label with the desired name:
        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(lblName, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Label)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)matches[0];
            ChangeLabel(newValue, lbl); // update it in a thread safe way
        }
    }

    private void ChangeLabel(string msg, Label label)
    {
        if (label.InvokeRequired)
            label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label.Text = msg; }));
        else
            label.Text = msg;
    }

}
```

Alternate version showing the creation of Class1 and wiring up of its Event during Form Load() so it's not attached to the Button handler:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private Class1 change = new Class1();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        change.ChangeLabel += Change_ChangeLabel;
    }

    private void Change_ChangeLabel(string lblName, string newValue)
    {
        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(lblName, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Label)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)matches[0];
            ChangeLabel(newValue, lbl);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeLabel(string msg, Label label)
    {
        if (label.InvokeRequired)
            label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label.Text = msg; }));
        else
            label.Text = msg;
    }

}
```

Now you simply need to raise that event *somehow* in Class1.  Just make sure it has a subscriber (is not null) before you raise it:

```
// in Class1
private void Foo()
{
    if (ChangeLabel != null)
    {
        ChangeLabel("label2", "SurName");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, do what i want. Really i don't have a button to call Class1, so, how do you change the code to move the part inside the botton into ChangeLabelText() in Class1?  Thanks

Comment: You need to wire up that event, so you'd probably do that at Form Load() time?  Then you simply need to raise that event, I'll edit above and post an alternate version.

Comment: Thank you so much. And how i can override `Class1 change = new Class1();` with other Classes that call the same method Class2, Class3,....

Comment: In that case, you may want to combine Shankar's approach of passing Form1 to those classes, but make the Public method receive the **Name** of the control and search for it as in my example.

Comment: I'm very thankfull for your help, but i'm studying C# and my english si not so good. I made the two methods Change_ChangeLabel and ChangeLabel public. I don't know Shankar's approach (and Google don't help). Can you help me more, please?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what is the context in which you are trying to change the label... however I have a few observations seeing your sample code.

First of all, to your question, one of the approaches could be as follows,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 change = new Class1(this);
    change.ChangeLabelText();
}

public void ChangeLabel(string msg, Label label)
{
    if (label.InvokeRequired)
        label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label.Text = msg; }));
    else
        label.Text = msg;
}

// dont allow UI elements to be accessed directly from outide
public string Fullname
{
    get
    {
        return label1.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        label1.Text = value;
    }
}

// dont allow UI elements to be accessed directly from outide
public string Surname
{
    get
    {
        return label2.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        label2.Text = value;
    }
}
```

You see that object of Class1 gets reference to the Form1.
Inside Class1.ChangeLabelText you may do something like the following,

```
class Class1
{
    Form1 _mainForm;
    public Class1(Form1 form)
    {
        _mainForm = form;    
    }
    public void ChangeLabelText()
    {
        //Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        //frm1.ChangeLabel("Surname", label2);
        _mainForm.Surname = "Surname";
    }
}
```

Observations after seeing your sample

1. It is a good practice not to expose/allow UI elements to be accessed by non-owner (Form1 is the owner in this case)
2. In button1_Click, you are already in a Form1 instance (object), however in ChangeLabelText, you are trying to create another instance of Form1.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I will study your code with calm. My intent is to do what on VB can be easily done, from a different class than MainWindow, like these: `MainWindow.TextBox1.Clear()` `MainWindow.TextBox2.Clear()`  `MainWindow.Label3.Visible = True`  `MainWindow.TextBox1.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20)`  `MainWindow.Label7.Text = "Done correctly!"`    `MainWindow.Label7.Text = "Errors, try again"`

Comment: I understand your code and is like what i now have: 5 different methods on the MainWindow  `public void CambiaTestoEtichette(string nuovoTesto)
        {
            label8.Text=nuovoTesto;
        }` each one to change the text on different label. I would like to use one method were i send the label number and the text

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass label as a parameter in your method

```
class Class1
{
public void ChangeLabelText(Label lbl)
    {
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm1.ChangeLabel("Surname", lbl);
    }
}
```

And in your button click -

```
change.ChangeLabelText(label2);
```

Comment: I can't put label2 in the button click method because should be label7, label1 or label5....i need one method were send the label number and a text

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 change = new Class1();
        change.ChangeLabelText(this);
    }

    public void ChangeLabel(string msg, Label label)
    {
        if (label.InvokeRequired)
            label.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { label.Text = msg; }));
        else
            label.Text = msg;
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public void ChangeLabelText(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
    {
        if(form != null)
        {
            var labelIdWhoseTextNeedsToChange = "label2"; // Or any dynamic logic to determine which label will have to be updated.
            var labelControl = form.Controls.Find(labelIdWhoseTextNeedsToChange, false);
            if(labelControl != null)
            {
                form.ChangeLabel("Surname", labelControl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have an error on Class1 public void ChangeLabelText(Control form): CS1061 control does not contain a findcontrol definition.  Tried to add using System.Web.UI but UI does no exsist on System.Web

Comment: Sorry mate, I did a silly mistake. Change the method signature to `public void ChangeLabelText(System.Windows.Form form)` and later you can find the control through form.Controls.Find() method. For example, form.Controls.Find("label2", false); // second param is false because I don't want to search through child controls

Comment: i already have using System.Windows.Forms; Changing the signature to System.Windows.Forms form, cuase System.Windows.Forms it's namespace but its used as type

Comment: It should be `System.Windows.Forms.Form form` I added full namespace for clarity. You can add using statement otherwise.

Comment: CS1061 'Form' does not contain a 'FindControl' definition and no 'FindControl' extension method is found that accepts a first 'Form' argument. Probably missing a directive using or reference to the assembly. On this line: `var labelControl = form.FindControl(labelIdWhoseTextNeedsToChange);`

Comment: @MassimoD.N. I've edited my answer. Please refer to it.